# Error: Cannot use GraphQLObjectType "__Directive" from another module or realm

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am trying to query data from GraphQL using Gatsby. I followed [Gatsby's](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/client-data-fetching/) instructions on querying data in pages with GraphQL but, I keep getting an error.

Error (this is what I need to fix more than the example below):

> Error: Cannot use GraphQLObjectType "__Directive" from another module
>   or realm  .   Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in
>   the node_modules   directory. If different versions of "graphql" are
>   the dependencies of other   relied on modules, use "resolutions" to
>   ensure only one version is installed.
>   https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions   Duplicate
>   "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
>   versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from
>   one   version used in the function from another could produce
>   confusing and   spurious results.

Any idea why this is happening? I only have one graphql instance in my node_modules folder

**Example of what I am working with:**

I am going to be importing my own data from GraphQL but for now as a proof of concept I am working on this Gatsby Rick and Morty Example (link above - I didnt bother with the axios demo yet).

index.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

// This query is executed at build time by Gatsby.
export const GatsbyQuery = graphql`
  {
    rickAndMorty {
      character(id: 1) {
        name
        image
      }
    }
  }
`

class ClientFetchingExample extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      rickAndMorty: { character },
    } = this.props.data

    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center", width: "600px", margin: "50px auto" }}>
        <h1>{character.name} With His Pupper</h1>
        <p>Rick & Morty API data loads at build time.</p>
        <div>
          <img
            src={character.image}
            alt={character.name}
            style={{ width: 300 }}
          />
        </div>
        <h2>Image of Rick's pupper</h2>
        <p>This will come from a request on the client</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ClientFetchingExample
```

gatsby-config.js:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
    options: {
      typeName: "RMAPI",
      fieldName: "rickAndMorty",
      url: "https://rickandmortyapi-gql.now.sh/",
    },
  },
...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My question was about the **error** and not the code (I added the code upon request for context). The error has been solved and instructions are included below.

I started by checking my `yarn.lock` for `graphql` instances. (I had two versions of `graphql`). The error says there should only be one.

To fix it:

1) I added the following to my package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
  "graphql": "^14.1.0"
}
```

2) I ran `npm install`

This fixed the error for me and hopefully will help someone else.

---

**Side note:** An alternative way to find what versions you may have in your node_modules run `find node_modules -name graphql` in the terminal.

For me it returned the two instances (not sure where the gatsby one came from):

```
node_modules/graphql
node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/graphql
```

To find versions use `grep version node_modules/graphql/package.json`

That's how I found I was running GraphQL 14.1.0

Answer (score 3):

I checked https://rickandmortyapi-gql.now.sh/ and found, that you have error in your query. It should be like that:

```
export const GatsbyQuery = graphql`
  query rickAndMorty {
    character(id: 1) {
      name
      image
    }
  }
`
```

I guess you tried to make named query, but created that wrong.

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
    options: {
      typeName: "RMAPI",
      fieldName: "character",
      url: "https://rickandmortyapi-gql.now.sh/",
    },
  },
```

...

Comment: I tried this but both come back with the error: 7:5  error  Cannot query field "rickAndMorty" on type "Query"

Answer (score -1):

run the following commands:
rm package-lock.json
rm node_modules

then:
npm/yarn install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).